# ngClass not affecting anything

Tags: angular, angular7, ng-class

I am using Angular 7. I got these CSS declarations:

```
.carddiv
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.gameMessages
{
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 3em !important;
}
.messageSuccess
{
    color : green;
}

.messageFailure
{
    color: red;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<section class="carddiv">
   <section class="gameMessages">
       <p [ngClass] = "{'messageSuccess':booli === true,
                        'messageFailure':booli === false}">{{currentMoveMessage}} </p>
</section>
<mat-card class="cardclass" [attr.data-index]="i" *ngFor="let card of cards; index as i"  (click)="onCardClick($event)">
  <mat-card-header class="cardheader">
    <mat-card-title> a card </mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header> 
  <img [src]="cards[i].pathToShow">
</mat-card>
</section>
```

Inside the component's class:

```
export class CardcomponentComponent implements OnInit 
{
  booli : boolean;
  currentMoveMessage : string;

  constructor(public cardService: CardService) 
  { 
    this.booli = true;
    this.currentMoveMessage = "message";
    ...
  }
...
```

When I load the page, there is no effect on the color of the text. When I'm using style directly it works, meaning when doing it like this:

```
<p style="color:red"> {{currentMoveMessage}} </p>
```

What's the problem with the ngClass?

Comment: There must be some more going on here, just re-created in a stackblitz seems fine. please edit in more code.

Comment: the part where it does work with the style directly puzzles me...

Comment: ^^ im guessing for readability for question , Yon, is the component pointing at the css correctly can you use one of the classes in normal use ie. class="messageSuccess". It may be the issue as syntax looks correct

Comment: the "gameMessages" class does affect the text as it should

Comment: maybe try .gameMessages
{
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 3em !important;
} there might be other styles interfering ?

Comment: the !important didn't work. I have edited with the full html and added a css class but which doesn't affect the font

Comment: do you see your class in the browser when you inspect HTML ?

Comment: Did you test with `<p class="messageSuccess">`?

Comment: This is what I see when inspecting:  <p _ngcontent-gmq-c1="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"> Select a pair of cards </p>

Comment: and with a direct class inside the p element it does work

Comment: Now you can try `<p [ngClass]="{'messageSuccess': true}">`.

Comment: try this way and toggle booli
       <p [ngClass] = "{'messageSuccess': booli,
                        'messageFailure': !booli}">{{currentMoveMessage}} </p> or        <p [ngClass] = "{'messageSuccess': (booli === true),
                        'messageFailure': (booli === false)}">{{currentMoveMessage}} </p>  this is how it says in documentation

Comment: @ConnorsFan that works as well

Comment: ha, that worked.. why can't i make the booli === true comparison?

Comment: Make sure that `booli` is always a boolean. It is in the constructor but it may change somewhere else in the code. For example, it may be set to the string `"true"` or `"false"`.

Answer (score 0):

See if you are able to reproduce the same in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zftgcv)

also you should set your `this.booli = true;` on `ngOnInit()` instead of the constructor, constructor is a typescript feature, `ngOnInit` runs when component is initialized, are you getting the `booli` from a `CardService` ?

Comment: it's so weird because when I changed to the 2nd way your wrote it worked, but then when I returned to the way I'm using in the question (which didn't work before) it just kept working..

Comment: are you missing space between messageSucess and booli ?in  "{'messageSuccess':booli === true

Comment: Maybe try setting this.booli = true; on ngOnInit() instead of the constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

The first section of your code has no problem. Check here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kur9tf

I just did a copy and paste. It works with no problem .